Call Recording Kotlin
Is Call Recording possible possible (today with Android 13) with my own kotlin app?
I am trying to recording call with MediaRecorder, like..
        val mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder(this).apply {
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)

But blank file without sound is creating..
I have studied and found that call recording is not possible after Android 10 ? then how some on Google play are providing Call Recording features..How they are providing this feature?
Any help will be appreciated..


New Android devices don't allow you to record calls. If you record audio, it will work well until call mode; then the microphone will be muted. Possible solutions:

1- Try your app on a rooted Android phone to bypass Android OS     limitations.
2- Try another Android device like the Samsung Galaxy S II, which may also work.
